# Storing Firefox extension preference using storage, data is not stored

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am building a Firefox extension where I need to store some preferences and from what I can tell, it is recommended to use the storage API for that. 
However, I have the problem that the data is not stored or at least I cannot get it back out from storage.

I have added `"permissions": ["storage"]` to my manifest.json file and this is my options.html site:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

<body>
  <p>Current redirect site <b id="current-redirect-site">www.duckduckgo.com</b></p>
  <form>
      <label>New redirect site</label>
      <input type="text" id="new-redirect-site" >
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
  <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the options.js file:

```js
function saveOptions(e) {
    browser.storage.sync.set({
        site_pause_redirect_site: document.querySelector("#new-redirect-site").value
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}

function restoreOptions() {
  var storageItem = browser.storage.managed.get('site_pause_redirect_site');
  storageItem.then((res) => {
    document.querySelector("#current-redirect-site").innerText = res.colour;
  });

  var gettingItem = browser.storage.sync.get('site_pause_redirect_site');
  gettingItem.then((res) => {
    document.querySelector("#current-redirect-site").value = res.site_pause_redirect_site;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreOptions);
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions);
```

Things I have noticed:

1. In the permission pane for the addon when testing, I cannot see the storage permission
2. I tried adding a console.log to the `saveOptions` function and that was not executed, I don't know if the extension allows for this though.

Any ideas? Have I made an obvious mistake I just have overlooked?

Comment: Use localstorage indeed this will solve your problem or check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/managed

Comment: @Rishab that is the code I am using. The extension example they link

Comment: did you added   "type": "storage" in your manifest

Comment: Yes I did :) and I have also tried to add the data object in the manifest, just update to what I want